# Not able to find a particular tag in html even though it has extracted by the parser

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, tags

I am trying to scrape data from one of the websites using python.
I'm trying to get some data, even though the script is getting the HTML tags which was specified
It is not able to find the some tags inside it.
Not sure what could be the problem.

Here is the code

```
soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
rows = soup.find('div', id='widgetContent').find_all('div', recursive=False)

for row in rows:
        price = row.find('span', class_='a-size-medium inlineBlock unitLineHeight dealPriceText').text
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/I354822/PycharmProjects/Python Practice/Amazon Text Exracting.py", line 40, in <module>
    price = row.find('span', class_='a-size-medium inlineBlock unitLineHeight dealPriceText').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

But I separately printed ***rows***, there I can find this tag.

Could someone help me in this.

Comment: share thr url from  which u r trying to scrape the data

Answer (score 0):

First check if the item exists for the class span , then try to retrieve the text property. For some elements in the required div , span element might not exists which is causing the above error

Try the below line of code:

```
rows = soup.find('div', id='widgetContent').find_all('div', recursive=True)
for row in rows:
        item = row.find('span', class_='a-size-medium inlineBlock unitLineHeight dealPriceText')
        if item:
            print(item.text)
```

Comment: That is fine, but I'm not getting the value into the item. even though the tag "a-size-medium inlineBlock unitLineHeight dealPriceText" is present in the rows

Comment: Added the code for recursive=True for the rows which would fetch the span tags. Found 280 price values for the items that has this span class.

Comment: How did you do that?